# Match a regex that was not matched before (url vs picture) in JS

Tags: javascript, angularjs, regex

I want to replace various patterns in a text by using regular expressions. I am currently differentiating "normal" links, images and YouTube videos:

image link -> < img src="link" >
yt -> < iframe href="link" >
website link -> < a href="link" >

I am using the following regex patterns:

```
    var image_reg = /(http:\/\/|https:\/\/).*(gif|jpg|jpeg|tiff|png)/ig;
    var yt_reg = /(https:\/\/youtu.be\/|https:\/\/www.youtube.com\/watch\?v=)\S*/ig;
    var url_reg = /https?:\/\/(www\.)?[-a-zA-Z0-9@:%._\+~#=]{2,256}\.[a-z]{2,6}\b([-a-zA-Z0-9@:%_\+.~#?&//=]*)(?!\")/ig;
```

I need to find a way how to make sure that a link is not an image or a YT video when being matched as a normal link.

I am currently using the following, imperfect solution:
I start with the image regex, followed by the YT regex. After that I run the link regex and replace every url that doesn't end with a " sign (and therefore is not a link inside the iframe or img tag)

However this is very risky and ugly.
What is a better way to achieve my goal?

Comment: How do you replace? Seems that by callback, why can't you just test the url inside that callback against img/yt templates and return text with no change if it matches? That way you won't even need three sweeps: you could just do general link global match, and make additional checks inside the callback.

Comment: Good idea, thx ;)

Answer (score 1):

You can globally search for all links only and, in the callback of replace method, check if the link is youtube link/image to decide how to process it.